# Jewish and Gregorian year's last digit

Tags: calendar

I've noticed that outside of the period between Rosh ha-Shana and 31 of December  (included) the last digit of the current year in both systems is always the same, e.g. 577**9** - 201**9**

What are the origins of this agreement or is it just a coincidence?

---

**UPD** <sup>*this update will remain here*</sup>

from the Wikipedia [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dionysius_Exiguus#Anno_Domini), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero#Historians)

> The Anno Domini era which is used to number the years of both the
>   Gregorian calendar and the Julian calendar was introduced in 525 by
>   Scythian monk Dionysius Exiguus (c. 470–c. 544), who used it to
>   identify the years on his Easter table. He introduced the new era to
>   avoid using the Diocletian era, based on the accession of Roman
>   Emperor Diocletian, as he did not wish to continue the memory of a
>   persecutor of Christians.
>
> **In the preface to his Easter table, Dionysius stated that the "present
>   year" was "the consulship of Probus Junior [Flavius Anicius Probus
>   Iunior]" which was also 525 years "since the incarnation of our Lord
>   Jesus Christ" without stating when this event occurred in any other
>   calendar. How he arrived at that number is unknown.**

The year 525 calculated by the monk appears to have coincided with the Jewish year ending with 5, hence the correspondence. Whether this was natural result of the calculations, deliberate or pure chance will remain a mystery.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: since i'd been met with an attitude i felt i'd be better off looking for an answer myself, the result has been added under **UPD**

Comment: 1. Do you suggest someone who started the AD system was careful to match the Jewish year? why not the tens? 2. Similarly, we, Jews, didn't consistently count years from the creation and the years Anno Mundo, we only know it based on some calculations.

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка sorry if you felt there was an attitude. I think many were puzzled by the question and your suggestion Jews would know why the Gregorian calendar started on a particular date. This being said you might consider editing your question and moving the answer part to an actual answer (it is possible to self-answer questions)

Answer (score 2):

Every year (say 2019) at around September time the current Jewish year (say 5779) will change (to 5780), because it will be Rosh Hashana.

There are only 10 numbers in the this instance, so there are 1/10 chances to be matched up. The Gregorian counting started in year 0 which was year 3760 by our counts. So they both started on an even number.

The coincidence that the last digit in the one’s place is the same, is just that.

Also, I think you meant to say from the beginning of the Gregorian New year until Rosh Hashana the one’s place stays the same.

спасибо за вопрос!

Comment: *Technically* the Gregorian calendar doesn’t have a year 0. I think what you meant to say is that our 3761 was their 1 CE.

Comment: that's what i meant by the word 'current', namely the main part of the year excluding the few months in the lead up to the Gregorian New Year... could you give a reference to the source of the assertion that 3760/1 Jewish year corresponds to the year 0/1 of the Gregorian calendar?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка What kind of source do you need? That was 2019 years ago, so just subtract 2019 from the current year of each calendar.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Nope. There's no year 0. Before 1CE was 1BCE.

Comment: @Daniel this is counting post factum, i'm asking how the agreement came about in the first place, coincidence?

Comment: ask the people who made the Gregorian calendar?

Comment: oh, guys i sense some attitude here, comes quite unexpectedly to be honest, are you unhappy with the question?

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка I think the question is not really sufficiently justified. It would be helpful if you could provide some reason why you'd think it might be anything _other_ than a coincidence. This is not a particularly unlikely coincidence and considering one could potentially ask the same question if it was just the short part of the year with the overlapping final digit, there's really a 20% chance of this happening.

Comment: No, I was being frank and/or serious. That may not be on topic here. Our calendar had be active for the prior 3000+ years, when 'a new' counting begins is not really related to the Jewish calendar.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel It’s 1 BCE and then immediately 1 CE on the Gregorian calendar. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero